# hwclock and sysclock are different

Tags: 14.04, sync, time, date, timezone

My Ubuntu 14.04 system is out of sync when I compare `date` and `hwclock`. 
Hwclock is simply 3 hours behind the system clock.  As I live in GMT+3 time zone. Sample output:

```
$ date
Sat Nov 26 13:18:40 +03 2016
$ sudo hwclock
Sat 26 Nov 2016 10:18:46 AM +03  -0.317417 seconds
```

So far solutions I tried:

- `hwclock --systohc`
- `hwclock -w --localtime`

None of these working, I mean it works until reboot. I also tried setting hwclock manually. Every time, I reboot my computer hwclock is 3 hours behind my sysclock. Is there a service manipulating time?

Other references I checked before I asking this question

- [hwclock, not in sync with system clock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175452/hwclock-not-in-sync-with-system-clock)
- [How to change system time or force a sync with hardware clock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229268/how-to-change-system-time-or-force-a-sync-with-hardware-clock)

Comment: Do you have another operating system installed in the machine (dual boot)? Or is this a virtual machine?

Comment: No it's the only OS installed on an old laptop.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the content of `/etc/default/rcS` and the output of `sudo hwclock --debug`

Comment: What is the output of `timedatectl`?